# How can I disable fullscreen mode in Kaltura's HTML5 media player?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-video, kaltura

I'm loading Kaltura's video player in a learning management system (essentially a CMS for educators and their students), and it gets presented inside an iframe. With current browser security protocols as they are, full screen viewing is not possible. I need to disable the fullscreen capability for this use case. Here's an idea how we have the embed set up:

```
loadMovie: function(id) {
    var autoPlay = this._autoPlay;
    var allowFullScreen = this._allowFullScreen;

    kWidget.embed({
      'wid': '_' + this._partnerId,
      'targetId': this._playerTarget,
      'uiconf_id': this._playerId,
      'entry_id': id,
      'params': {
        'wmode': 'transparent',
        'allowFullScreen': allowFullScreen, // not working for html player
      },
      'captureClickEventForiOS': true,
      'readyCallback': function (playerId) { // autoPlay movies
        var kdp = document.getElementById(playerId);

        kdp.kBind('mediaReady', function() {
          kdp.sendNotification('doPlay');
        });
      }
    });
}
```

I've been able to hide the fullscreen button with CSS, but a user can still (intentionally or inadvertently) double-click the playback area to achieve fullscreen. Because of the iframe issue, the video essentially disappears, leaving the user confused and unable to easily close the player modal.

I'm passing a data attribute from the movie links to the player init function to indicate when fullscreen should be unavailable. I just need to find out how to actually do the disabling. Kaltura's documentation has not been helpful.

I've also fiddled with legacy Flash params, but they have no effect on the HTML 5 player. I'm using version 2.11. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put this in a script tag:

```
mw.setConfig('EmbedPlayer.EnableFullscreen', false);
```

Comment: The second line did the trick, though I can find that parameter nowhere in Kaltura's docs. Thank you.

Comment: is `mw` a kaltura widget object?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you simply put a div overlay on top of the player with z-index, say 10000. That way, even if some double-clicks, they are clicking on the DIV and nothing happens. Continue with the CSS button hiding.

Comment: That would also disable all other controls in the player. Also, I'd prefer not to increase complexity if there's a method to do it programmatically (and I'd be very surprised if there wasn't).

Comment: Well, you can control the height of the overlay to not come over the controls... I mean, if nothing else is available, you can try this out

Comment: The controls are scattered all over the playback area. Thanks for the suggestion, but it won't work for me.

Comment: How about this link? http://knowledge.kaltura.com/faq/how-change-existing-full-screen-button-control-area-text-button

Comment: I need to programmatically disable fullscreen for some circumstances, not across the board.